# Skip ssl certificates check for Maven in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus, sonatype

I am trying to integrate Jenkins maven plugin to pull dependencies from a local nexus server. When the build starts I end up with the following Error

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I have tried to disable it by suppling the following wagon ssl properties as MAVEN_OPTS:

```
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true 
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true 
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true
```

I have also tried to add the certificate to the 
    javahome/lib/security/cacerts of the JVM.
 using the key tool

are there any additional things I should try to disable the self-signed certificate check.

Comment: Are you sure you added the cert to the node *that is running the mvn step*?